# Custom ArrayAdapter has made my ListFragment rows not respond to clicks

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a custom ArrayAdapter called ResultsAdapter that, upon the selection of a specific row by a user, should open a new activity that details that specific row.  This worked fine when the adapter I used was a simple ArrayAdapter, but since extended that and creating my own (to allow multiple pieces of data in each row), the ability to respond to clicks on each row has gone away.

I've narrowed it down (I think) to the fact that I need to specify the `onClickListener` and what it needs to do in my customer adapter, but I'm not exactly sure what to specify.  Previously, most of the "clickability" was handled in the custom ListFragment I am using.

Here's the custom adapter class I'm using:

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context myContext;

public ResultsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId);
   myContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){            
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null); //must be overall layout  
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //this is where the clicking actions need to be defined, right?
        }
    });

    TextView venName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowName);
    TextView venAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowAdd);

    venName.setText(VenueList.getVenueName(position)); 
    venAddress.setText(VenueList.getVenueAddress(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

And here's the custom ListFragment class:

```
public class ListFragmentClickable extends ListFragment{

  private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_results, container, false);
      return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      updateDetail(position);
  } 

  public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
      public void onItemSelected(String name, String geo, String id, String address);
  }


  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
        listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
      } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement ListFragmentClickable.OnItemSelectedListener");
      }
  }

  public void updateDetail(int position) {
      // Get data from VenueList
      String name = VenueList.getVenueName(position);
      String geo = VenueList.getVenueGeo(position);
      String id = VenueList.getVenueId(position);
      String address = VenueList.getVenueAddress(position);

      listener.onItemSelected(name, geo, id, address);
  }
```

}

Could anyone help point me to why the ability to click has been lost?  How can I restore it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has nothing to do with the custom adapter, but rather with the implementation of fragments in the app.  I had to set the xml to include `android:clickable="true"` for the ListView portion of the activity.